# Defining new keywords with font-lock-add-keywords breaks/overrides variable-name coloring (emacs)

Tags: emacs, text-coloring, font-lock

I was trying to get emacs to color some additional keywords in C.  In particular, I to add RESTRICT.  I did:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
      (lambda ()
        (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                    '(("\\<\\(RESTRICT\\)\\>" . font-lock-keyword-face))) ))
```

However, this (unsurprisingly) just causes emacs to color instances of "RESTRICT" with keyword-face.

"restrict" (lower case) is already part of emacs' knowledge of C keywords.  So if I declare:

```
int * restrict foo;
```

The "int" is colored with type-face, "restrict" is colored with keyword-face, and "foo" is colored with variable-name-face.  But with my new RESTRICT word, if I declare:

```
int * RESTRICT bar;
```

"int" is colored as before, and RESTRICT is colored with keyword-face.  But "bar" has no effects on it.  Without my rule in place, "RESTRICT" would be colored variable-name-face, and "bar" would be unmodified, which is proper.

Anyway, the question is: how can I make emacs color "bar" in the second code-block with variable-name-face?  I want emacs to actually treat "RESTRICT" as a keyword in the language (so that variable names get colored), not just color instances of "RESTRICT" a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that you somehow want to override this definition in cc-langs.el (part of cc-mode):

```
(c-lang-defconst c-type-modifier-kwds
  "Type modifier keywords.  These can occur almost anywhere in types
but they don't build a type of themselves.  Unlike the keywords on
`c-primitive-type-kwds', they are fontified with the keyword face and
not the type face."
  t    nil
  c    '("const" "restrict" "volatile")
  c++  '("const" "volatile" "throw")
  objc '("const" "volatile"))
```

however, i'm no expert in cc-mode but i couldn't find an obvious way to override this binding.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I don't know how to override that either.  I'm super new to this; that font-lock thing was the most complex change I've tried.  Anyway machine only has a cc-langs.elc file; I assume the "c" means "compiled."  But [link](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CudaMode) appears to be handling CUDA files by extending the c-mode?  So maybe I can do something similar to that... once I understand how that thing works.  Now that I know I want to append to c-type-modifier-kwds, should I make a new thread?